# Waiting on AVAssetExportSession synchronously

Tags: swift, multithreading, concurrency, avfoundation

I'm trying to wait for `AVAssetExportSession.exportAsynchronously` to complete synchronously, and here's what I've got so far:

```
func foo() {
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

    session.exportAsynchronously {
        defer {
            semaphore.signal()
        }
        // ...
    }
    semaphore.wait()
}
```

I was wondering, is there any possibility that blocking the current thread while `exportAsynchronously` is running will cause a deadlock?

In other words, is `exportAsynchronously` guaranteed to run on another `DispatchQueue`?

Comment: "I'm trying to wait for AVAssetExportSession.exportAsynchronously to complete synchronously". Well don't. Just. Don't.

Comment: @matt I know its not good, but I'm just curious

Comment: You could write a unit test for your hypothesis.